# When does $(x^x)^x=x^{(x^x)}$ in Real numbers?

Tags: roots, exponentiation

I have tried to solve this equation:$(x^x)^x=x^{(x^x)}$ in real numbers I

got only $x=1,x=-1,x=2$ , are there others solutions ?

Note: $x$ is real number .

Thank you for your help .

Comment: Do you know about negative powers of real numbers?  Or should be use only positive real numbers?

Comment: no, I want all real number positive or negative

Comment: So, for most $x < 0$, your values $x^{x^x}$ are complex?  How to choose branches?

Comment: Take $\log$ on both sides repeatedly, and divide it up into cases $x \neq 1$, $x<0$

Comment: I did some experiment with Maple.  Choosing "principal values" for the powers, note that for $x=-1.3$ we get
$$
(x^x)^x \approx -1.496126580-.4346649524 i,\qquad
x^{(x^2)} \approx .8757194745-1.288582076 i
$$ so be careful when you claim these are equal.

Comment: Maple can't find to you the form of solution, only we want a clear mathematical method for proving .

Comment: Ok, I see, so one has to be careful with negative values, as one can get complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose $x>0$. Taking logs,
$$ x \log{x^x} = x^x \log{x}. $$
Applying the property $\log{a^b}=b\log{a}$ gives
$$ x^2 \log{x} = x^x \log{x}. $$
So at this poing either $\log{x}=0$ (i.e. $x=1$) or
$$ x^2=x^x. $$
Taking logs again,
$$ 2\log{x} = x\log{x}, $$
and we already have established that $\log{x} \neq 0$, so $x=2$.

Right, now let's think about $x<0$. We have
$$ (x^x)^x = x^{x^2}, $$
and $x^2>0$. Dividing gives
$$ 1 = x^{x^x-x^2} $$
Okay, now let's cheat and write $x=e^{i\pi} r$, $r>0$. Then we have
$$ 1 = (re^{i\pi})^{(re^{i\pi})^{re^{i\pi}}-r^2}. $$
Since $r>0$, we can at least pull it out of things...
$$ 1 = (re^{i\pi})^{r^{-r}e^{-i\pi r}-r^2} = r^{r^{-r}e^{-i\pi r}}r^{-r^2}e^{i\pi (r^{-r}e^{-i\pi r})}e^{-i\pi r^2} = e^{r^{-r}(\cos{\pi r}-i\sin{\pi r})\log{r}} r^{-r^2} e^{\pi r^{-r}(i\cos{\pi r}+\sin{\pi r})} e^{-i\pi r^2} $$
Okay, let's get an absolute value.
$$ 1 = e^{r^{-r}\cos{\pi r}\log{r}} r^{-r^2} e^{\pi r^{-r}\sin{\pi r}} $$
We can happily take the log of this:
$$ 0 = (r^{-r}\cos{\pi r}-r^2)\log{r}+\pi r^{-r}\sin{\pi r} = r^{-r}(\cos{\pi r}\log{r}+\pi\sin{\pi r})-r^2\log{r} $$
The dominant term on the right-hand side is clearly $-r^2\log{r}$, and therefore we can see that all the roots will have small $r$ (suffices that $r^2\log{r}>\log{r}+\pi$ for there to be no subsequent roots, for example—and $3$ is quite sufficient). $r=1$ is clearly a root. However, it is clear that the right-hand side tends to $-\infty$ for $r \to \infty$, and more careful examination shows that it also tends to $-\infty$ for $r \to 0$. The function is analytic, so there should only be finitely many roots; in particular, the behaviour suggests an even number. Okay, so that hasn't got us far: let's look at the argument.
$$ e^{-ir^{-r}\sin{\pi r}\log{r}} e^{i\pi r^{-r}\cos{\pi r}} e^{-i\pi r^2} = e^{i(\pi r^{-r}\cos{\pi r}-r^{-r}\sin{\pi r}\log{r}-\pi r^2)} $$
The factor in the exponential needs to be a multiple of $2\pi i$.

Okay, at this point I give up analysis and start drawing pictures.[image]

Log of the absolute value. Obviously only two roots, one at $r=1$.

[image]

Argument, with lines of $2k\pi$. Obviously the other root in the former diagram does not have the right argument. Hence $r=1$ (i.e. $x=-1$) is the only other root.

Comment: :I don't know  why your solution without any upvote, however it's seems to me very good and very nefty looking .and I se to accept it

Answer (score 3):

Just a sketch for $x>0$:

Let $y=x^x$ and rewrite $x^y=y^x$ by taking $log$'s as $\log (x)/x = \log(y)/y$.

For each $x \in (1, e)$ there is a unique $y(x)$ such that $f(x) = f(y(x))$.

As a function of $y(x)$, you can show that it is increasing. So we are looking for solutions of $y(x) = x^x$. Because $g(x) = y(x)-x^x$ is increasing, it can have only one root. So there is only one positive $x$ that satisfies the equation with $x\neq 1$.

EDIT: For integer $x < 0$ non-integer, things get complicated because we will involve complex numbers and raising numbers to complex powers.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
for $x>1$
$$x^{x^2} = x^{x^x}$$
$$x^2=x^x$$
$$2\log x=x\log x$$
$$x=2$$

Comment: but i got x=2 I asked about more solutions

Comment: that means there is no other solution greater than $2$

Answer (score -2):

You have $(x^x)^x = x^{x^2}$. Assuming $x \not \in \{-1,1,1\}$,
$$x^{x^2} = x^{x^x}$$
happens if and only if the exponents agree, i.e. $x^2 = x^x$ which under our assumptions is equivalent to $x=2$.

Comment: @GEdgar fixed it thanks

Comment: Is $(x^y)^z = x^{yz}$ really true for negative $x$?  Like $((-1)^2)^{1/2} = -1$?